# Generic wrapper class

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Given the following hierarchy:

```
class A
{
}
class B : A
{
    public void Foo() { }
}
class C : A
{
    public void Foo() { } 
}
```

This is a third-party library and I can't modify it. Is there a way I can write some kind of 'generic templated wrapper' which would forward the Foo() method to the apropriate object passed as constructor argument?
I ended up writing the following, which uses no generics and seems rather ugly:

```
class Wrapper
    {
        A a;
        public Wrapper(A a)
        {
            this.a = a;
        }

        public void Foo()
        {
            if (a is B) { (a as B).Foo(); }
            if (a is C) { (a as C).Foo(); }
        }

    }
```

I'd love some template constraint like `Wrapper<T> where T : B or C`.

Comment: I assume that the main problem is that `Foo` is not `virtual` in `A`, right?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If `A` does not have `Foo`, you need to either use `dynamic` (see [Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16438935/335858)) or use a little trick with lambdas and overloading:

```
class Wrapper {
    private Action foo;
    public Wrapper(B b) {
        foo = () => b.Foo();
    }
    public Wrapper(C c) {
        foo = () => c.Foo();
    }
    public void Foo() {
        foo();
    }
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
var wb = new Wrapper(new B());
wb.Foo(); // Call B's Foo()
var wc = new Wrapper(new C());
wc.Foo(); // Call C's Foo()
```

This shifts the decision on what method to call from the moment the `Foo` is called to the moment the `Wrapper` is created, potentially saving you some CPU cycles.

Comment: Thanks everybody! I think I go for your solution as there are more Foo-like functions, which I omitted for brevity. I also have to use the Wrapper several times across my code and dynamic seems too in-line solution.

Answer (score 8):

No, the two `Foo` methods are completely unrelated as far as the compiler is concerned. The simplest way of doing this *without* knowing about the individual types to start with would be to use dynamic typing:

```
public void Foo()
{
    dynamic d = a;
    // Let's hope there's a suitable method at execution time!
    d.Foo();
}
```

Generics won't help you here, as far as I can tell. It's not like there's some interface (at least none that you've shown) which you can constrain `T` to.

You could pass in an `Action` as well:

```
Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper(b, b.Foo);
```

which makes it slightly less convenient for the caller, but very general...

Comment: this is Skeet paunch. you rock Skeet.

Comment: merge Jon's "action passing" with dasblinkenlight's suggestion and a T4 template and you shoudl get very reasonable and maintainable solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm reluctant to suggest it, but as you can not modify the library.. If this is not performance-critical, recall the `dynamic` keyword :)

```
class Wrapper
{
    public dynamic theAorBorC;

    public Wrapper(A a){theAorBorC=a;}
    public Wrapper(B b){theAorBorC=b;}
    public Wrapper(C c){theAorBorC=c;}

    // or even...
    // public Wrapper(object anything){theAorBorC=anything;}

    public void CallFoo()
    {
        theAorBorC.Foo();
    }
}
```

Edit: in all other cases, I'd personally use lambdas similarly to what dasblinkenlight has shown - to get compile-time checking. It can be easily autogenerated i.e. with T4s or any other text generator.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a parallel hierarchy that does contain the `Foo()` method at the root level.
Using factory methods you can create a Wrapper instance for either type. For this to work you need to know the exact type of your `A` instance when you call the factory method

```
abstract class Wrapper {
    public abstract void Foo();

    //factory methods
    public Wrapper FromB(B instance) {
        return new WrapperB(instance);
    }
    public Wrapper FromC(C instance) {
        return new WrapperB(instance);
    }
}

class WrapperB {
    private B instance {get; set;}
    public WrapperB(B instance) {
        this.instance = instance;
    }

    public void Foo() {
        instance.Foo();
    }
}
class WrapperC {
    private C instance {get; set;}
    public WrapperC(C instance) {
        this.instance = instance;
    }

    public void Foo() {
        instance.Foo();
    }
}
```

Edit: this is basically the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16439038/1296709)